# SqlDataAdapter update error cause

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, exception, sqldataadapter

I have code like this:

```
DataTable dataTable;

// filling table with data from db, closing connection
// modifying table

// trying to save it
// "some_table" is the same table data was loaded from

var connection = new SqlConnection(some_connection_string);
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from some_table", connection);
var cbMar = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
SqlTransaction transaction = null;

dataAdapter.InsertCommand = cbMar.GetInsertCommand();
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = cbMar.GetUpdateCommand(true);
dataAdapter.DeleteCommand = cbMar.GetDeleteCommand(true);

transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
dataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;
dataAdapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;

dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
```

And here, at `Update`, I am getting an exception:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.
> System.Exception {System.FormatException}
>
> InnerException:
> Input string was not in a correct format.
> System.FormatException

As I understand, it is because I have set string value to integer database column.

**Question**: how to find exactly which column and row caused this exception?

I was able to build .pdb file for System.Data.dll and can step into it, but while I am trying to add any variables from System.Data.dll to watch, I am getting an error saying it was optimized out. As I understand, System.Data.dll doesn't have a debug version.

Comment: One of your DataGridCells that should contain an integer has a value that is not an integer

Comment: Yes, i understad. Issue here is that in this table i have several thousands rows and about 150 columns. It is difficult to check them all. Is there any way to find out error source automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in a comment above the problem is probably caused by a cell of your grid that is expected to contain an integer value but it is not.

To help you find which row contains the invalid cell you could add the event handler for the RowUpdated to your SqlDataAdapter with code like this

```
....
dataAdapter.RowUpdated += onUpdate;
....


private void onUpdate(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Row[0]);
    if (e.Errors != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Errors.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("At row with key=" + e.Row["somecolumntoidentifytherow"]);
    }
}
```

While debugging you could put a breakpoint inside the if block and look around the e.Row object that contains the invalid value. (now you still have 150 columns in the itemarray to look at). Are you sure that presenting this wall of data is of any utility to your user?

Comment: Thank you, will try this solution tomorrow. About users i am not sure, i am developer, not user, but there are a lot of column filters available, column pinning, fast navigation to column and so on, so, i believe each user can configure grid as he wants.